# Binding variable to find methon in phalcon Model

Tags: php, phalcon

I have the following code inside my controller:

```
$release = $this->dispatcher->getParam("release");
$builds = Builds::find([
   "release_name = :release_var:",
   "bind" => ["release_var" => $release]
]);
$this->view->release =  $release;
$this->view->builds = $builds;
```

And the problem is that builds variable is empty. Query return rows only when I change the variable $release for the static string, like "release_var" => "release_123".
I am sure that release variable is not empty, it is even accessible from the view.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Did you dump $release to see what was in it?

Comment: Did you confuse `$this->dispatcher->getParam("release");` with `$this->request->get("release");` ?